# cant install chatterbot (full command output)

Tags: python, chatterbot

I've been trying to install chatterbot for a while now, and I keep getting an error that says:

> "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> 'c:\users\myusername\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe'
> 'c:\users\myusername\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip'
> install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix
> 'C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-47p4l01_\overlay'
> --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython
> 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0'
> 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0' Check the logs for
> full command output."

and I couldn't find another way of installing this, can you help me, please?...